# Converting SQL statements into Drools Rules

Tags: drools

I have to port some stored procedures into Drools. Since stored procedures follow an imperative programming model, I am finding it tricky to convert them into Drools rules. For example, I could have a series of case statements like this:

```
case
    when <condition 1> then <action 1>
    when <condition 2> then <action 2>
    when <condition 3> then <action 3>
end
```

Because there is an ordering implied in the evaluation above, i.e. evaluate condition 1 first, then condition 2, and then condition 3 I am finding it difficult to translate that into Drools. In Drools, I just write the rules without order specified. How can I achieve the ordering implied by the above SQL into Drools rules? Do I have to create a JPBM process and have a rule task for each of the conditions in the above SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up `salience` and `activation-group` in the manual.

The `salience` property gives you a mechanism for defining priority of rules.

The `activation-group` property enables you to enforce that only one rule in a particular group is activated.

By combining those, you have something approximating a case/switch statement.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I'm going to use a combination of activation-groups and salience. As you know, the with activation-groups if one of rules fire in that group then the others are ignored. This is exactly what I want to mimic from the stored procedures.